# Which is the better way to avoid magic string keys? Using string const keys in a class or using enumeration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My idea is to avoid magic string keys in my Asp.Net MVC application.
To do so, I want to create string constant keys to be shared in the application.

For example, I can write `TempData[MyClass.Message]` or `TempData[MyEnum.Message.ToString()]` instead of `TempData["Message"]`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public const string Message = "Message";
}
```

and

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   Message,
   Others
}
```

My questions are: Which is the better way to avoid magic string keys? Using string const keys in a class or using enumeration together with `ToString()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is up to preference and usage.

You are able to accept the enumerated values in a strongly typed way:

```
public void SomeFunction(MyEnum someValue)
{
}
```

Or

```
TempData[MyEnum.Message]
```

With const strings, you can't.

You also have a built-in way to enumerate the values in an enum.

There is a third option which you haven't presented, and that is to place your "constants" in your configuration settings (App.Config).  This will let you configure them after compile time.  You might not need this now, but you might in the future, so it is worth considering.

One of these may be better for globalization purposes.  I'm not sure which, since I've never globalized an app.  Whichever works in satellite assemblies, I assume.

Basically, it comes down to what `TempData` is, and how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 5):

You should go for const strings as it can containt spaces/special chars as well, if those are your requirements. Otherwise change TempData to `Dictionary<MyEnum,object>` which is better approach.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered, but I want to throw in my thoughts here. You're focusing too closely on the mechanics and not the problem you're having - which is "how do I get away from breaking my application when I decide TempData["Message"] should actually be Session["Alert"]" (or something like that.

Magic strings do not apply to dictionary keys - they apply to messages sent to routine that does something based on the string value. Something like "SetStatus('current')" would be magical.

What you want to do here is to use a centralized method for handling messaging. Create yourself a helper class and call it "Messaging" if you like - ir get all Railsy and call it "Flash". Then, you could do something groovy like "Flash.Message("Hi there")" - this keeps the mechanism hidden (as it should be) and you're not worrying about those silly dictionary keys.

You can also expand this - "Flash.Alert('Oh NO!')" - etc.

Comment: Good post. as for me i like to store data like "SetStatus('current')" in db and(or) in cache. Because if i want to change this i don't need rebuild my app.